# Write a Python program that replaces all periods in a paragraph with "\n"

Tags: python-3.x

Is there anybody who can get me started on this? I have very very few knowledge about python and at my college python is not even taught. However, in my Linux class my instructor insists in writing a program that replaces all periods within a paragraph with a new line. I do not want you to make my homework, but I feel a bit lost with this assignment. My pre knowledge is in c and java, both introduction levels. Can you please give me a hint on even how to start on this? Thank you very much.

Comment: `the_string.sub('.','\n')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a string method called [replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm). You can use it like this.

```
string = """this is a test. This is another. And so on."""

newstring = string.replace(".", "\n")

print(newstring)
```

You can try yourself [here](https://repl.it/Fx0n).